# Appmaker Typeerror suggests _equals method is a property I cannot call

Tags: javascript, backend, google-app-maker

I want a function which changes the company of a customer to a "nocompany" company, whenever a company gets deleted. The code looks like this:

```js
function afterCompanyDeletion(companyID)
{
   var noCompanyId= "1";
   var noCompany =app.models.Companies.getRecord(noCompanyID);
   var query = app.models.Customers.newQuery();
   query.filters.Company.Id._equals(companyID);
   var records= query.run();

    for (var i in records) {
      i.Company=nincsCeg;      
    }
}
```

But I get an error message that says "TypeError: Cannot call property _equals in object [object Object]. It is not a function, it is "undefined". at afterCompanyDeletion (Server:6)" I am not sure what's wrong with my code, would really appreciate some help,  thank you!

[image about the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq7WI.png)

Comment: There is probably more than one issue with this code, but for starters are your company records stored with a number or string Id? If it's the former then your code is setting it as a string instead of a number and there is your first problem. Also, what is your actual purpose for this code because other than fetching a record from Companies model the first two lines appear to be useless? Also if your Company field in Customers model is a relation then setting a relation to 'nocompany' will not work, it can only be null since it is looking for a foreign key.

Comment: One more thing, the operator `._equals` does not work with (companyID) it would have to be `._equals = companyID;`.

Comment: Check the official documentation for performing queries https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query

Comment: I store the company records with a number id. I fixed the issude you mentioned, yet still when throws type mismatch error. It says it expects a string, when I use the .getRecord() method. How can the key be string, if my primary key is the ID which is an integer?

Comment: nevermind, I found a way around it, by converting the companyID to string

Answer (score 0):

The right way to apply the filter is

```
query.filters.Company.Id._equals=companyID;
```

This is because equals isn't a function, its a property of the filter you are modifying.